# tmap, ggplot and missing polygon (Barbados)

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, tmap

I am used to work with tmap plus ggplot with the dataset included in tmap: "World" but I just found out that it does not include Barbados for certain reason. I need the area and MULTIPOLYGON. I do not know how to get it from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rnaturalearthhires` package includes Barbados as a separate country. This may help.

```r
library(rnaturalearthhires)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tmap)


bb <- ne_countries(country = 'Barbados', scale = 10, returnclass = 'sf')


tm_shape(bb)+
  tm_polygons()+
  tm_layout(main.title = "Barbados")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>